# Удаленный доступ к MySQL через Workbench

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, apache2, virtualbox, mysql-workbench

Что есть:

1. Установил на VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.
2. В настройках виртуальной машины (далее Ubuntu) стоит NAT и Сетевой мост, т.е. видит Интернет по NAT и является частью физической локальной сети.
3. Гостевой системе установлен статический адрес (192.168.1.99), который пингуется на всех других машинах локальной сети.
4. Установлено Apache + PHP + MySQL + PhpMyAdmin + Nginx
5. На любой машине локальной сети можно ввести в браузер 192.168.1.99/phpmyadmin и успешно пройти авторизацию в PhpMyAdmin

Но я привык и мне более удобен MySQL Workbench.
Я пытаюсь добавить новое соединение:
- в hostname: 192.168.1.99
- port: 3306
- uresname: root
- password: соответствующий
и нажимаю Тест, то мне пишет, что не может соединится к серверу MySQL по адресу

```
192.168.1.99:3306
```

Если в консоли Ubuntu ввести команду netstat -tln, то я понимаю, что

```
0.0.0.0:80 - это слушают все адреса и порт 80 для показа моего сайта, а
127.0.0.1:3306 - это скорее всего слушает MySQL.
```

Т.е. я понимаю, что MySQL случает порт 3306 только на localhost.

И теперь вопрос:
Как сделать, что-бы он кроме localhost слушал и другие адреса?
Другими словами, как подключиться к серверу MySQL, установленного на VirtualBox, удаленно средствами MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы на виртуальной машине брандмауэр не блокировал этот порт, или вообще отключите его.

Comment: Для начала объяснить mysql-ю, что слушать надо на всех интерфейсах (my.cnf): bind-address=0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы настроить удаленный доступ с других IP:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Ищем секцию [mysqld] и изменяем значение bind-address на 0.0.0.0

У меня файл my.cnf был почти пустой. Там было много текста в виде коментов, то я просто добавил:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Перезагружаем сервер:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Проверяем, что теперь слушает демон MySQL:

```
  netstat -tln
```

должно быть 0.0.0.0:3306

Дальше пытаемся подключится через MySQL Workbench или другим клиентом - управлялкой базами данных и получаем сообщение о том, что наш комп не может соединяться с MySQL-сервером.

```
host ‘192.168.1.83’ is not allowed to connect to this mysql server
```

где 192.168.1.83 - это IP-адрес моего ПК.

Дело в том, что MySQL не только умеет ограничить доступ извне к самому серверу, но еще и определить пользователей для доступа удаленно к определенным базам или даже таблицам.

Нужно создать пользователя и дать ему нужный доступ. Детальней расмотрим SQL-запрос на создание пользователей:

```
GRANT [тип прав] ON [имя базы данных].[имя таблицы] TO 'имя пользователя'@'его ip-адрес';
```

Что-бы создать суперпользователя, типа root, только со своим именем, USER_NAME, с полными правами для всех баз данных с доступом с любого IP и с паролем YOUR_PASSWORD:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER_NAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

вот еще примеры:

создать пользователя для конкретной БД:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_db`.* TO USER_NAME@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
```

создать пользователя и ограничить доступ только для определенного IP:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_db`.* TO USER_NAME@'192.168.1.83' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
```

или вовсе только только для работы с сервера, например только через PhpMyAdmin:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO USER_NAME@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
```

Если определились с выбором SQL-запроса, тогда его можно запустить в том же phpMyAdmin или в консоли:

Заходим в MySQL:

```
mysql -u root mysql -p
```

Пишем нужный SQL-запрос, например:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'megaadmin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'superparol' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Для того, чтоб изменения вошли в силу запустите запрос на обновления:
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

выходим с MySQL:
    EXIT;

Так же это можно сделать в графическом интерфейсе PhpMyAdmin без ввода SQL-запроса. После авторизации под рутом в PhpMyAdmin, заходим во вкладку "Учетные записи пользователей". Там все интуитивно понятно. Ниже опустив экран можно выбрать нужные привилегии на SQL-запросы (Данные), на создание баз данных и таблиц (Структура) и на управлении сервером (Администрирование), а также можно установить ограничение на использование ресурсов.